# What to do about large number of questions posted as answers

Tags: discussion, answers

In relation to all other (15+) SE sites that I'm active on, this one has a very large number of (follow-up, me-too) questions posted as an answer.
(I'm not proficient with SEDE, so I cannot give actual numbers).

I have no issue with flagging them as 'not an answer' when reviewing them, because that is a very quick action.
I'm also not afraid that this will put off new users. It is a clear signal to them - if they think their question is important, they will take the effort to write a new one.

Still, I wonder, would there be anything else we could do to reduce the noise?

Comment: I've often wondered if we could put up a notice or warning if there's a '?' anywhere in their post.  But I presume anything implemented would occur cross-site.

Comment: Is this site bad even compared to non-STEM ([Science, technology, engineering, and mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science,_technology,_engineering,_and_mathematics)) sites?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Even [cooking.se] seems to have less of these ;-)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: As one data point, [math.se] really doesn't have any questions-as-answers that I notice.

Answer (score 5):

> Still, I wonder, would there be anything else we could do to reduce the noise?

There's probably something that *could* be done, but in any case it is beyond the authority of Travel.SE users or mods as the UI for new users posting an answer is beyond our control. Try re-posting your question on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

> I have no issue with flagging them as 'not an answer' when reviewing them, because that is a very quick action.

You are correct that it's not a big deal. Flag the answer and it will be removed shortly by a mod or by the review queue. No need for any radical measures to prevent those kinds of answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some questions attract many more of these than others: particularly, questions which are about a common situation that may be faced by many people, but with slight variants.

Such questions can be [protected](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) by moderators and 15K users, so that they don't allow answers from brand-new users.  So if you notice a particular question getting a lot of non-answers, you can flag it for moderator attention and suggest that it be protected.  When you reach 15K reputation, you'll be able to protect questions by yourself.